# MSSQL 17 is using only half of the avaliable processors

Tags: sql-server, hyper-v, sql-server-2017

I'm currently testing the VM with MSSQL 17 installed. It has 16 cores in two sockets and 100GB of RAM.

When I start the test, only 8 cores are working. The cores from the second node are not used by MSSQL.

All cores are online in the MSSQL. Configuration is almost default (Max degree of parallelism is set to 4)

Why the cores from the second node are not used?

Comment: Which SQL Server edition are you using? Web, Standard, Enterprise? How is the *VM* configured? When you say `The cores from the second node are not used` it sounds like the VM itself is using only one socket

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a Standard edition and hit its limitation.

It allows only 4 sockets. If your VM configured as 8 sockets x 2 cores, you will see only a half of them

You can check it by running:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

The workaround is to reconfigure VM to present cores as:
1 socket x 16 cores, or 2x8 or 4x4

More information on limitations here: [Editions and supported features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017)

**Update:**

> - When I start the test, only 8 cores are working.
> - Configuration is almost default (Max degree of parallelism is set to
>     4)

Another possible reason is that your test uses a single of few connections. 
SQL Server sessions are bound to workers and workers bound to schedulers.

So it is about such chain:
Connection->Session->Worker->Scheduler->Core.

Currently MAXDOP set to 4, which means that single session can load maximum 4 cores and 2 sessions can load 8 cores.

By setting MAXDOP to 16 you will allow all CPUs to be used by multithreading

```
USE [yourDB]
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 16;
```

But again, your session is bound to worker and worker bound to some single core

Comment: It was my first assumption. But i found this in the error log :
"SQL Server detected 2 sockets with 8 cores per socket and 8 logical processors per socket, 16 total logical processors; using 16 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing." It seems the MSSQL is able to use all 16 cores but for some reason is not using half of them